# Pago con tarjeta en aplicación android

Tags: android

Necesito integrar en mi aplicación alguna forma de pagar con tarjeta de crédito, sin tener que usar un web view(es la única opción que he encontrado) y que no sea con PayPal.

¿Alguien podría darme alguna opción?

Gracias.

Comment: No necesariamente con _WebView_ puedes hacerlo manualmente haciendo uso del sdk de paypal https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La opción para android sería  **[Google Wallet](https://www.google.com/wallet/)** que tiene como propiedades:

- Relaciona una tarjeta de credito.
- Relaciona una cuenta PayPal.
- Relaciona una tarjeta Google Play.

Existen varias opciones, además de Google Wallet y Paypal, en base a un estudio que realice, las demás opciones tal vez son menos costosas pero tienen desventajas como el tipo de cambio permitido, paises donde puede aplicarse el pago, soporte.

Skrill
https://www.skrill.com/en/

Dwolla
https://www.dwolla.com/

Payoner
https://www.payoneer.com/in/

2Checkout
https://www.2checkout.com/

Selz
https://selz.com/es

Stripe
https://stripe.com/

WePay
https://go.wepay.com/

etc...

Comment: Gracias por la opciones, sabes si alguna es gestionada por redsys?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es una recomendación, [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) te puede venir muy bien.

Te dejo el link a la [integración con Android](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android)

Answer (score 0):

He trabajado con Stripe, Conekta, Paypal y PayU.
Puedo decir que la mejor opción y con más amplio rango de cobertura es BrainTree (También administrado por Paypal).
Puedes integrar pagos con tarjetas de crédito y débito de todo el mundo, bitcoin, AndroidPay, ApplePay, Vemmo y tiene integraciones de terceros para utilizarlo aún más fácilmente.
Además, los primeros $50,000 no te cobra ningún tipo de comisión.
Puedes verificar los detalles aquí: https://www.braintreepayments.com/

Downside: No se puede integrar solamente en la Aplicación Móvil, debes configurar un servidor que le acompañe para procesar los pagos.

Comment: Lamentablemente, también es de las más caras...